# How to test if variable is in specified format in Bash?

Tags: regex, bash

My Bash script accepts an argument of a version number, in the following format: `#.#.#.#.dev` or `#.#.#.#.prod`, where `#` can be any number, for example: `3.6.212.0.dev`.

I want to verify that the argument is in the right format (contains all the 4 numbers separated by dots and includes `.prod` or `.dev` in the end).

I'm not sure how to achieve this, so far I've tried this:

```
re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $1 =~ $re ]] ; then
echo "error: Incorrect version specified; must be in the format of #.#.#.#.env" >&2; exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
re='^([0-9]+\.){4}(dev|prod)$'
if ! [[ "$1" =~ $re ]] ; then
  echo "error: Incorrect version specified; must be in the format of #.#.#.#.env" >&2; exit 1
fi
```

See a [Bash demo online](https://ideone.com/QseeXS).

`^([0-9]+\.){4}(dev|prod)$` is a POSIX ERE compliant pattern that matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `([0-9]+\.){4}` - four occurrences of one or more digits and a dot
- `(dev|prod)` - `dev` or `prod` substring
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you! The part where you explain about each part of the Regex is really helpful for newbies like myself!